# SQLite - how to subtract one value from another

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a database with 3 tables; tblCustomers, tblBookings, tblFlights.

In the Bookings table I have the number of tickets sold for each flight, and in the Flight table the Capacity of each flight.  I want to return the remaining number of tickets left for each flight.
I have tried subtracting the capacity from the tickets, but can't get the syntax right,  I know I have created a JOIN and it does not return the correct information.

I have tried:

```
SELECT *, (Capacity - Tickets)
from tblFlights, tblBookings
where (Capacity - Tickets)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually cross joining the tables, but you should do an `INNER` or `LEFT` join based on the related columns of the tables, which I believe must have names like `flight_id`:

```
select *, (f.Capacity - b.Tickets) tickets_left
from tblFlights f inner join tblBookings b
on b.flight_id = f.flight_id
where (f.Capacity - b.Tickets) > 0
```

I kept the `where` clause because you use it in your code.

If the relation of `tblFlights` and `tblBookings` is not `1:1` then you also need aggregation:

```
select f.*, (f.Capacity - coalesce(b.Tickets, 0)) tickets_left
from tblFlights f left join (
  select flight_id, sum(Tickets) Tickets
  from tblBookings
  group by flight_id 
) b on b.flight_id = f.flight_id
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, but it shows the remaining tickets after each booking, how do I see the total remaining tickets for the flights after all the tickets sold, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should be something like this:

```
SELECT *, (Capacity - Tickets) as Remaining
    from tblFlights Tf, tblBookings Tb 
    where Tb.id = Tf.id and (Capacity - Tickets) > 0
```

You can also use a join statement:

```
SELECT *, (Capacity - Tickets) as Remaining
    from tblFlights Tf
    join tblBookings Tb on (Tf.id = Tb.id)
    where (Capacity - Tickets) > 0
```

What you had initially creates permutations between the two tables.